# Recursive Quicksort throws stack overflow exception

Tags: c#, recursion, quicksort, stack-overflow

I have written a recursive quicksort algorithm in c# using Visual Studio. What seems weird is ,when the input which is the collection of number that will be sorted,is lower than 9500 in array it gives the result in both best,worse,and avarage case. However, when the input is greater than 9500 it throws a stackoverflow exception. I know there were another question that is nearly same as my question in site but I did the condition also which can recursive.

---

```
public int[] quick(int [] myarray,int p,int r)
    {
        int q;
        if (p < r)
        {
            q = partition(myarray, p, r);
            quick(myarray, p, q - 1);
            quick(myarray, q + 1, r);
        }
        return myarray;
    }
    public int partition(int [] myarray, int left, int right)
    {
        int i = left - 1;
        int tmp = 0;
        int pivot = myarray[right];
        for (int j = left; j < right; j++)
        {
            if (myarray[j] < pivot)
            {
                i = i + 1;
                tmp = myarray[i];
                myarray[i] = myarray[j];
                myarray[j] = tmp;
            }
        }
        tmp = myarray[i + 1];
        myarray[i + 1] = myarray[right];
        myarray[right] = tmp;
        return i + 1;

    }

 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Stopwatch mwatch = new Stopwatch();
        Program quickprogram = new Program();
        int[] mydizi = new int[9000];
        //int counter = 9000;

        //initialization of quick array
        for (int i = 0; i < mydizi.Length; i++)
        {
            mydizi[i] = i + 1;

        }

       int[] result = new int[9000]; //return array
        //time is starting
        mwatch.Start();
        //algorithm is called
        result = quickprogram.quick(mydizi,0,mydizi.Length-1);

        //result is returned from quickprogram
        for (long j = 0; j < result.Length;j++)
        {
            Console.Write(result[j] + ",");
        }
        mwatch.Stop();
        //time is up
        //Printing the time that show how it takes
        Console.Write("Ms:" + mwatch.Elapsed.Milliseconds + " S:" + mwatch.Elapsed.Seconds + " Mn:" + mwatch.Elapsed.Minutes + " Hr:" + mwatch.Elapsed.Hours);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: NO NEED TO SHOUT !!!

Comment: If a recursive algorithm gets a stack overflow, it usually means your test for the bottom case is not correct.

Comment: Your code works fine on my computer when I run it with an array of 1,000,000 elements.

Comment: Thanks for all but I got what I needed.By optimizing my algortihm now it wokrs well .Neverthless thanks again...

Comment: If the reason for a question's downvote has been corrected, it would be helpful for those downvoters to reverse their vote. We don't want to discourage new users who see this question from asking for programming help.

Answer (score 0):

You do a worst-case quicksort. The array is already sorted and you try to sort it again.

Next, your partition() code indeed looks strange:

```
int i = left - 1;                   // i = left-1
int pivot = myarray[right];
for (int j = left; j < right; j++)  // j = left
{
    if (myarray[j] < pivot)
    {
        i = i + 1;                  // now i = left-1+1 = left = j
        tmp = myarray[i];
        myarray[i] = myarray[j];
        myarray[j] = tmp;           

        // congratulations!
        // you successfully exchanged a value with itself!
    }
```

In the end result, you call quick() recursively with these arguments (with array size = 9):

```
 quick( 0, 8)
> quick( 0, 7)
>> quick( 0, 6)
>>> quick( 0, 5)
>>>> quick( 0, 4)
>>>>> quick( 0, 3)
>>>>>> quick( 0, 2)
>>>>>>> quick( 0, 1)
>>>>>>>> quick( 0, 0)
>>>>>>>> quick( 2, 1)
>>>>>>> quick( 3, 2)
>>>>>> quick( 4, 3)
>>>>> quick( 5, 4)
>>>> quick( 6, 5)
>>> quick( 7, 6)
>> quick( 8, 7)
> quick( 9, 8)
```

You see that doing this with 9000 elements will easily reach a recursion level of 9000 nested calls.

Comment: But how do 9.000 calls exhaust a 1MB stack?